Let $\mathbb{R^*}$ be the multiplicative group of nonzero real numbers.Which of the following statements are true?
Let $\mathbb{R^*}$ be the multiplicative group of nonzero real numbers.Which of the following is true?
1.
If $H\subseteq\mathbb{R^*}$ is a subgroup such that $x^2\in H$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R^*}$, then $H =\mathbb{R^*}$
2.
If $H\subseteq\mathbb{R^*}$   is a subgroup such that $x^3\in H$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R^*}$, then $H =\mathbb{R^*}$. 
3. There is no subgroup of $\mathbb{R^*}$ of index $2$.
4. There is no subgroup of $\mathbb{R^*}$ of index $3$.

My attempt:Since $\mathbb{R^+}\leq\mathbb{R^*}$ of finte index $2$.Hence option $3$ is not correct.For option (1) the same example will work.Hence option (1) is also not correct.Kindly someone guide me for other options.Thank you.

If $H$ satisfies the condition in 2, then it contains $-1$ and every positive real.

Where is the context? This reads to me like a half-hearted stab at a homework problem. -1

For statement $2$, if $x^3 \in H$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^*$, then $x=(\sqrt[3]{x})^3 \in \mathbb{R}^*$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^*$ (using the existence of cube roots).
For statement $4$, suppose that $H$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{R}^*$ of index $3$. Then, a known fact in group theory states that a normal subgroup of index $n$ must contain all $n$th powers (hint: consider the quotient group). So, $H$ contains every cube and hence must contain all nonzero real numbers by statement $2$, which contradicts $H$ having index $3$.
